# Some Google contacts are not synchronized

Tags: contacts, sync, google-account

I am a long time user of Android and Google and have all my contacts in Google Contacts, synchronized on my phone. So do my wife and my children.

Within the same domain (managed via Google Apps) I have one other account which behaves differently (my father's - the only person who does not do anything fancy with his phone).

Almost all of his contacts in Google synchronize to his phone. There are a few (10% maybe) which do not. They exist in his Google account and do not get synchronized. They belong to "My Contacts", like others which do synchronize. They are not special (the name is in ASCII, there is a normal email address and a normal phone number associated).

When creating a new contact on the phone,  it synchronizes to Google.
When creating a new contact in Google, it synchronizes to the phone.

Contacts from all accounts on the phone are set up to be displayed (and they do).

I deleted and recreated on Google one of the contacts which does not synchronize. It synchronized to the phone.

**In other words, I am stuck with some contacts which for an unknown reason refuse to synchronize from Google to the phone (the other way round it works). What could be the reason?**

Is there a way to reset the synchronization short of deleting/recreating the offending contacts (this is cumbersome as I do not know which contacts are missing, except if I review all of them one by one).

Comment: Where  were these contacts created, in Google-contacts, or imported (via gmail)? Maybe you find something from this point of view.